# Can't Add Parse Object to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

When I run the following code, I get the data from the Parse.com database, but when I try to print out the array that I try to store this data in, it gives off a null value. Help!

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Resolution"];
    [query whereKey:@"event" equalTo:event_name_label.text];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                [resolution_names addObject:(NSString*)[object objectForKey:@"resolution_name"]];
                NSLog(@"%@", [object objectForKey:@"resolution_name"]);
            }
            NSLog(@"%@", resolution_names);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
```

I have properly declared (I think) the NSMutableArray resolution_names, but it returns null upon logging it.

Here is my header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MenuViewController : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UILabel *event_name_label;

NSString *event_id;
NSString *event_name;
NSMutableArray *resolution_names;
NSMutableArray *resolution_pro_speakers;
NSMutableArray *resolution_con_speakers;
NSMutableArray *resolution_results;

NSMutableArray *billtrackertablevalues;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *event_name_label;

@property (nonatomic) NSString *event_id;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *event_name;

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *resolution_names;
@property (nonatomic)  NSMutableArray *resolution_pro_speakers;
@property (nonatomic)  NSMutableArray *resolution_con_speakers;
@property (nonatomic)  NSMutableArray *resolution_results;

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *billtrackertablevalues;

@end
```

Once again, I am able to see the values of [object objectForKey:@"resolution_name"] in the console, but when I try to output the values of the NSMutableArray resolution_names, it just says "(null)" on the console.

Answer (score 2):

A very common mistake with `NSMutableArray`s is to forget to initialise them. Since I do not see any initialisation of your array and it returns (null) I guess it’s worth a try.

Try to add this to your `viewDidLoad` or `init` method.

```
self.resolution_names = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple things. You do not need to declare the iVar, just the property will do. Next, you should specify your array as `strong` which tells the compiler to retain the object. So, `@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *resolution_names;` becomes `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *resolution_names;`.

Lastly, you should override the default getter to lazily instantiate the array when your app needs it.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)resolution_names
{
  if(!_resolution_names){
    _resolution_names = [NSMutableArray array];
  }
  return _resolution_names;
}
```

Comment: Properties are strong by default.